# Remove duplicate from the value of particular dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to remove duplicate values from the particular key in dict
for example

I'm have

```
data = [{'NAME':'John','AGE':23,'NUMBER':345},
        {'NAME':'Michel','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
        {'NAME':'RAHUL','AGE':23,'NUMBER':347},
        {'NAME':'Susea','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
        {'NAME':'Wincent','AGE':23,'NUMBER':342}]
```

In above i need to unique the 'NUMBER' key as unique
Note: {'NUMBER':346} occurs 2 times.
I need output as

```
data = [{'NAME':'John','AGE':23,'NUMBER':'345'},
        {'NAME':'Michel','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
        {'NAME':'RAHUL','AGE':23,'NUMBER':347},
        {'NAME':'Wincent','AGE':23,'NUMBER':342}]
```

(i.e) removing any of the duplicate record for particular key duplicate

Pls help me

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
data = [{'NAME':'John','AGE':23,'NUMBER':345},
        {'NAME':'Michel','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
        {'NAME':'RAHUL','AGE':23,'NUMBER':347},
        {'NAME':'Susea','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
        {'NAME':'Wincent','AGE':23,'NUMBER':342}]

filtered_data = []
seen = set()
for item in data:
    number = item['NUMBER']
    if number not in seen:
        filtered_data.append(item)
        seen.add(number)
# filtered_data is deduped
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
key = 'NUMBER'
seen = set()
res = []
for entry in data:
    if not entry[key] in seen:
        res.append(entry)
        seen.add(entry[key])
```

Result:

```
>>> res
[{'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'John', 'NUMBER': 345},
 {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Michel', 'NUMBER': 346},
 {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'RAHUL', 'NUMBER': 347},
 {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Wincent', 'NUMBER': 342}]
```

Use a `set` to hold the already seen values. For large lists this is much more efficient than using a list such as `val in seen_list`.

Comment: Ya.. This is right.. I tried this. But when we do this for Lakhs of records , its taking too much time. I need to do this in less time. can u help  me?

Comment: @Arjun You did not show your approach and did not mention that the run time is important. Using a set is much faster than using a list for duplicate checks. Are you sure you use a set?

Comment: Sorry for that. 
I'm using dict and that is dynamic content. I'm writing as service that we ca n give many key values in dict.

Answer (score 0):

Create unique list of Number.

**Algo**:

1. `uni_no` is unique number list.
2. `data1` final output of filter process.
3. Iterate on `data` by for `loop`
4. check if `NUMBER` is present iterator item.
5. If not then add to `data1` and add Number to `uni_no`

**Demo**:

```
>>> data = [{'NAME':'John','AGE':23,'NUMBER':345},
...         {'NAME':'Michel','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
...         {'NAME':'RAHUL','AGE':23,'NUMBER':347},
...         {'NAME':'Susea','AGE':23,'NUMBER':346},
...         {'NAME':'Wincent','AGE':23,'NUMBER':342}]
>>> 
>>> data
[{'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'John', 'NUMBER': 345}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Michel', 'NUMBER': 346}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'RAHUL', 'NUMBER': 347}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Susea', 'NUMBER': 346}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Wincent', 'NUMBER': 342}]
>>> uni_no = []
>>> data1 = []
>>> for i in data:
...     if i["NUMBER"] not in uni_no:
...         uni_no.append(i["NUMBER"] )
...         data1.append(i)
... 
>>> data1
[{'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'John', 'NUMBER': 345}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Michel', 'NUMBER': 346}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'RAHUL', 'NUMBER': 347}, {'AGE': 23, 'NAME': 'Wincent', 'NUMBER': 342}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps:
1. Create an empty list for your found_numbers.
2. Iterate over all dictionary entries.
3. For each dictionary, look to see if the value for the number key is in your found_numbers list.
If the number exists this is a duplicate entry.  You can remove it from your list
Else the number is not found so this is the first instance of a dictionary with this number.  We need to add this number to the found_numbers list.

Note:  This assumes a first come first serve attitude towards duplicate entries.